# XPath - Need to Parse Some Html

Tags: html, xpath, web-scraping

I have some Html in a doc that looks like this:

[image]

I am using this code:

```
    Dim web As New HtmlWeb
    Dim doc As New HtmlDocument
    doc = web.Load("http://www.reedmantollchryslerdodgejeepram.com/new-inventory/index.htm?search=&saveFacetState=true&year=2017&lastFacetInteracted=inventory-listing1-facet-anchor-year-0")

    Dim label = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class='facetmulti-label  make']")
```

That "kind of" works because I get this result (as one item in a collection of two):

[image]

Ideally, the end result of this scrape would be "Chrysler (35)"

I'm new to XPath...can this be done?

EDITED:

To be clear (hopefully), on the webpage, I am trying to parse these quantities (i.e., the "Chrysler (35)" and "Fiat (3)"):

[image]

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the value attribute in the input tag to find the relevant part of the html then get the parent with */..*:

```
"//input[@value='Chrysler']/..//text()"
```

Or select the label using filtering by the input child that has the attribute *value='Chrysler'*:

```
"//label[@class='facetmulti-label  make'][input/@value='Chrysler']//text()"
```

Or using *contains* to find the label using the label text:

```
"//label[@class='facetmulti-label  make' and contains(.,'Chrysler')]//text()"
```

You can also  combine any  with *normalize-space* if you want to remove newlines etc..

```
"normalize-space(//input[@value='Chrysler']/..)"
```

Comment: Ok, but I in the OuterHtml field I get this whole string: <input .... > - I am just trying to parse out "Chrysler" and the number "(35)" - Does that make sense?

Comment: @PierreMFiorini, I tested all the examples and they all return the text

Comment: Ok - I see they work...Thanks!...I need to digest this for a bit

Comment: I added a little more explanation so hopefully that helos